# Changing table prefix and schema of ABP.IO

Tags: database, schema, prefix, abp

I am trying to change the database table prefix and schema for ABP.IO (https://www.abp.io/). I have found two properties for it but not sure where to change to affect everything. Does anyone have an idea?

The properties:

`Volo.Abp.Data.AbpCommonDbProperties.DbTablePrefix`
`Volo.Abp.Data.AbpCommonDbProperties.DbSchema`

Answer (score 3):

You can find them under **YourProject.Domain** project, YourProject**DbProperties.cs** file.

Answer (score 0):

You fix value for Volo.Abp.Data.AbpCommonDbProperties.DbTablePrefix Volo.Abp.Data.AbpCommonDbProperties.DbSchema and re-migrate and update-database.

My way:

Volo.Abp.Data.AbpCommonDbProperties.DbTablePrefix = "Myprefix"
Volo.Abp.Data.AbpCommonDbProperties.DbSchema = null;