# Remove prefix from Volo.Abp table names

Tags: c#, abp

I am trying to use ABP Framework Core 8.

After running *Add-Migration* and *Update-Database*, all of the created tables have `Abp` prefix.
Such as: `AbpUsers`, `AbpRoles`, `AbpFeatures`, ...

How can I remove `Abp` from table names?

Is it possible to remove prefix in free version for default tables?

Can I use ABP Framework for backend only not for frontend?

I have tried following:

1. ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

       modelBuilder.ChangeAbpTablePrefix<Tenant, Role, User>(""); 
   }
   ```
2. ```
   builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
   {
       b.ToTable("Users", AbpIdentityDbProperties.DbSchema);


   }); inside some override class in migrator.
   ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ABP.IO How to change DbTablePrefix for all Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194496/abp-io-how-to-change-dbtableprefix-for-all-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

```
public static class *YourProjectName*EfCoreEntityExtensionMappings{

}
```

Inside it there will be a method

```
public static void Configure()
```

Inside it there will be

```
OneTimeRunner.Run(() =>
{}
```

Inside this scope, add:

```
string newDbTablePrefix = "";
AbpIdentityDbProperties.DbTablePrefix = newDbTablePrefix; //Identity
```

It will rename AbpUsers to Users.

Answer (score 0):

The table names are prefixed with "Abp" by default to prevent conflicts with existing tables in your database.

To remove the "Abp" prefix from table names:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class ApplicationDbContext : AbpDbContext<MyProjectDbContext>
{
    // Add DbSet properties

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyProjectDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Configure table names without "Abp" prefix
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Feature>().ToTable("Features");
        // Add configurations for other entities as needed...
    }
}
```

***Ans: Can I use ABP Framework for the backend only not for frontend?***

Yes, you can use ABP Framework for the backend only without the frontend modules. You can simply create your backend services using ABP and omit the frontend modules.